# HTML/Javascript multiplication table that takes inputs and highlights the answer on table

Tags: javascript, html

As the title states, I need to make a multiplication table using JS and HTML that takes two user inputs and highlights the answer on the table. I have the table made, I'm just struggling with how to take the user inputs from the ids "leftOp" and "rightOp" and highlighting the answer on the table.

```js
var color_td;
document.write("<table border='1px'>");

for(var i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
  document.write("<tr style='height:30px;'>");

  for(var j = 1; j < 11; j++) {
    if(j == 1 || i == 1) {
        color_td = "#ccc";
    }
    else {
        color_td = "#fff";
    }

    document.write("<td style='width:30px;background-color:" +            color_td + "'>" + i*j + "</td>");
  }
  document.write("</tr>");
}

document.write("</table>");
```

```html
<input type='text' id='leftOp' value=''>
<input type='text' id='rightOp' value=''>
```

Comment: `document.write` probably isn't what you want here

Comment: Don't have time to write out the full answer right now, but generally, look into document.getElementById.  You can use that to both get the values for processing and then set them after they are processed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Important tip: Doesn't use `document.write` when creating elements and appending new things to DOM, use the correct API for that, such as `document.createElement` that you can manage the elements much better. In my code below I'm using it to show you as example.

After creating the table, you'll need a function to get the values and the do the verifications and Maths. Also, add the operands `i` and `j` (example: "`i_j`") as the `id` of each `<td>` (take care to not have any repeated id), that way you'll have an easy way to found the `td` you should highlight.

Also, you should have some way to clear the background color of the td which is already highlighted, for that I used an auxiliar function called `cleanTds`.

Take a look:

```js
var color_td;
let table = document.createElement("table");
document.body.appendChild(table);

for(var i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
  let tr = document.createElement("tr");
  tr.style.height = "30px"
  table.appendChild(tr);
  var color_class;

  for(var j = 1; j < 11; j++) {
    if(j == 1 || i == 1) {
        color_class = "grayBg";
    }
    else {
        color_class = "whiteBg";
    }
    let td = document.createElement("td");
    td.className = "tdClass " + color_class;
    td.id = i +"_"+ j;
    td.style.background = color_td;
    td.textContent = i * j;
    tr.appendChild(td);
  }
}

document.getElementById("calc").onclick = (ev) => {
  cleanTds()
  let val1 = document.getElementById("leftOp").value;
  let val2 = document.getElementById("rightOp").value;
  if (val1 == null || val1 == ""){ val1 = 0}
  if (val2 == null || val2 == ""){ val2 = 0}
  
  let tdResult = document.getElementById(val1 + "_" + val2)
  if (tdResult != null){
    tdResult.style.background = "green";
  }  
}

function cleanTds(){
  let tds = document.querySelectorAll("td");
  for (var td of tds){
    td.style.background = ""
  }
}
```

```css
.tdClass{
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.grayBg{
  background: #ccc;
}

.whiteBg{
  background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<input type='text' id='leftOp' value=''>
<input type='text' id='rightOp' value=''>
<button id="calc">Calculate</button>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was trying to pull off. You're a lifesaver. My professor isn't very good at explaining, and I'm sorta lost in javascript at the moment. Will definitely be using this as a reference! =D

Answer (score 3):

I tried a simple answer with your code style.

Just bind the event "onkeyup" of your inputs to a function that highlight the result cell.

To identify each cell, I add an id and a class to each one. The id is a concatenation of the two indexes and the class difference between border cells and other cells.

To hightlight the rersult cell, you use the inputs values and build the id of the result cell with them.

Don't forget to reset the cells colors on each invocation.

```js
var color_td;
document.write("<table border='1px'>");

for (var i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
    var id;
    var cellClass;
    document.write("<tr style='height:30px;'>");

    for (var j = 1; j < 11; j++) {
        id = 'cell-' + i + '-' + j;
        if (j == 1 || i == 1) {
            color_td = "#ccc";
            cellClass = "border-cell";
        }
        else {
            color_td = "#fff";
            cellClass = "result-cell";
        }

        document.write("<td class='" + cellClass + "' id='" + id + "' style='width:30px;background-color:" + color_td + "'>" + i * j + "</td>");
    }
    document.write("</tr>");
}

document.write("</table>");

function inputChange() {
    var left = document.getElementById('leftOp').value;
    var right = document.getElementById('rightOp').value;

    if (!left || !right || left > 10 || left < 1 || right > 10 || left < 1) {
        return;
    }

    var cells = document.getElementsByClassName('result-cell');
    for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
        var cell = cells[i];
        cell.style.backgroundColor = '#fff';
    }
    
    var cells = document.getElementsByClassName('border-cell');
    for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
        var cell = cells[i];
        cell.style.backgroundColor = '#ccc';
    }

    var resultCell = document.getElementById('cell-' + left + '-' + right);
    resultCell.style.backgroundColor = '#5fc047';
}
```

```html
<input type='text' id='leftOp' value='' onkeyup="inputChange()">
<input type='text' id='rightOp' value='' onkeyup="inputChange()">
```

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started.  it's triggered when the enter key is pressed

```js
var color_td;
document.write("<table border='1px'>");

for(var i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
  document.write("<tr style='height:30px;'>");

  for(var j = 1; j < 11; j++) {
   var idName = 'R'+i + 'C' + j;
    if(j == 1 || i == 1) {
       
        color_td = "#ccc";
    }
    else {
        color_td = "#fff";
    }

    document.write("<td id='"+idName + "'style='width:30px;background-color:" +            color_td + "'>" + i*j + "</td>");
  }
  document.write("</tr>");
}

document.write("</table>");

left = document.getElementById("leftOp");
right = document.getElementById("rightOp");

document.getElementById("rightOp")
    .addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
        left = document.getElementById("leftOp");
        right = document.getElementById("rightOp");
        
        var idName = 'R' + leftOp.value + 'C' + rightOp.value;
      
       document.getElementById(idName).style.backgroundColor = "lightblue";
    }
});
```

```html
<input type='text' id='leftOp' value=''>
<input type='text' id='rightOp' value='' >
```